# How long does the voting fraud detection script take to run?

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I was a target of serial down voting yesterday on Stack Overflow and today that has been reversed. I know that the voting fraud detection script is run around 03:00 UTC every night (according to this Meta answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/214189). Just thinking about the amount of data it may have to inspect made me curious - how long does the voting fraud detection script take to run?

Comment: I'm not sure it's run once a day, it may only be that it's effect is shown once a day.

Comment: @yo' According to this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me - "Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run"

Comment: Why does it matter, exactly?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It doesn't matter. I'm just curious.

Comment: I guess the script takes 6 to 8 ...